# can we get all activity without user ID in getstream

Tags: php, getstream-io

Can we get stream without user id i.e. without $results = $user_feed_1->getActivities(5, 10);

I want to get all streams for all users. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is currently not possible to retrieve activities stored on many feeds in a single request. You can only read activities from one feed at the time.

You can achieve that by sending all activities to a global feed. The suggested way to do this, is to use the `to` targeting field as documented here: http://getstream.io/docs/#targetting

For example:

```
$userOneFeed = $client->feed('user', '1');
$data = [
    "actor"=>"user:tommaso",
    "verb"=>"reply",
    "object"=>"question:35312059",
    "to"=>["flat:global"]
];
$userFeedOne->addActivity($data);
```

this code adds an activity to $userOneFeed **and** to the global feed. If you add the `to` field every time you add an activity, you will be able to fetch all activities by reading from the global feed.

```
$globalFeed = $client->feed('flat', 'global');
$globalFeed->getActivities(5, 10);
```

Comment: With laravel we get feed like :                                                                   $feed = \FeedManager::getNewsFeeds($user_id)['flat']; How to implement   getfeed as above